# Nested query params with Tesla

Tags: get, elixir, query-string, tesla

This is the URL I'm trying to hit:

`/example/?fields=*&filter[platform][eq]=111&order=date:asc&filter[date][gt]=1500619813000&expand=yes`

My code:

```
  get("/release_dates",
      query: [
        fields: "*",
        order: "date:desc",
        expand: "games",
        filter: %{
          date: %{gt: unix_now},
          version_parent: %{not_exists: 1}
        }
      ]
    )
```

I'm trying to perform a Tesla GET request that has those `filter[date][gt]=123123123123` type query param.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: How is the code you posted _ever_ connected to the query you claim to be trying to hit? Who the heck is Tesla? What is the desired outcome? What error do you receive?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to generate a URI with a filter for "greater than" timestamps which are variable.

According to your inital example, this can be done like this:

```
Tesla.get("/example/",
  fields: "*",
    filter: [
    platform: [
      eq: 111
    ]
  ],
  order: "date:asc",
  filter: [
    date: [
      gt: unix_now
    ]
  ],
  expand: "yes"
)
```

Note that `/example` is a relative reference and can only be resolved with a base URI. Better provide a complete URI.

If you want to experiment with the URI generator in an `iex` console, you can use `iex -S mix` in your project directory and then use the following functions:

```
Tesla.build_url("/example/",
  fields: "*",
  filter: [
    platform: [
      eq: 111
    ]
  ],
  order: "date:asc",
  filter: [
    date: [
      gt: 123123123123
    ]
  ],
  expand: "yes"
) |> URI.decode()
```